# Nginx load balancing doesn't work on location path

Tags: nginx

The load balancer configuration /etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf is:

```
upstream myproject {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:81;
}

upstream myproject2 {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:82;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myproject;
  }

  location /b {
    proxy_pass http://myproject2;
  }
}
```

The url

```
localhost
```

is working, but the url

```
localhost/b
```

is not working and there is the error message

```
404 Not Found
```

in the web browser.

What could be problem?

The url

```
localhost:82
```

is working.

Note: The situation is simplified. Later I will add more urls etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the url

```
localhost:82/b
```

wasn't working. When I got it working, I fixed the problem.